# Blocking of port 25

Tags: google-compute-engine

What do I need to do to resolve the port lock problem? 25. I need to install a panel for the email and I'm not able to access it. I have a T.I programmer and he can not do anything because of this problem. I tried to find a solution but I could not.

Comment: Can you help me? Please, I need it urgently.

Answer (score 1):

**Google Compute Engine** *does not allow outbound connections on ports 25, 465, and 587*.

By default, these outbound SMTP ports are blocked because of the large amount of abuse these ports are susceptible to.

In addition, **having a trusted third-party provider such as SendGrid, Mailgun, or Mailjet** relieves Compute Engine and you from maintaining IP reputation with your receivers.

See more in https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/